# Issues in setting time to uidatepickerview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification, uidatepicker, alarm

Im working with alarm concept in my app, I used uilocalnotifications, and datepickerview to set time. My datepicker shows time only.

I used the code,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
}
```

The time for datepicker is set as the current date but the second value is not set to 0;
it goes to the second value of the viewdidloaded, ie,for ex, 12:30:14

```
- (void)scheduleNotification {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");

if (cls != nil) {
    UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
notif.fireDate = [datePicker date];
notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notif.alertBody = @"My Alarm";
notif.alertAction = @"Show";
notif.soundName = @"Show.mp3";
notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:reminderText.text
forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];

notif.userInfo = userDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];

[notif release];

}
```

alarm is set to play w.r.t datepicker

I tried to set the second of datepicker to 0 using the code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

NSDate *reqdate = [self.datePicker date];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit |   NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )

   fromDate:reqdate];

NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )

   fromDate:reqdate];


   NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];


[dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];

[dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];

[dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents 0]];

NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

datePicker.date = itemDate;

}
```

But if I set the alarm suddenly the notifier fires the alarm , I didnt know whats happening here,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `notif.fireDate` to be in the future. Try for example this

```
    // Get the current date
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    //make it later
    NSDate *pickerDate =   [now dateByAddingTimeInterval: (60.0 * 5)]; // 5 minutes in the future
    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];

    // Set up the fire time - or manipulate it here to whatever time/date in the future you may like!
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    [dateComps setMinute: [timeComponents minute];
    [dateComps setSecond:0];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];


    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
```

That will work nicely...

Answer (score 1):

You are not using your variable `dateComponents`. You are setting the `itemDate` just with the  `timeComponents`, so the date will be perhaps January 1, 0001.

Possibly, the notification becomes due immediately (`fireDate` is in the past).